# Nginx cache issue

Tags: caching, nginx

My pages doesn't change since yesterday (except if I remove the code, upload, and put the new code), I don't know why, I didn't install cache system and I just remove memcached... I tried sendfile at Off, but same result. I have nothing on var/cache/nginx.

Any idea ? Nginx 1.2.1/debian 7

Comment: Are you sure you are updating the pages in the right location? Have you checked the output in Chrome Developer Tools or Fiddler?

Comment: Yep :/ I tried 2 times